# Using a double integral to evaluate a diverging integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Evaluate the integral
$$\int_0^{\infty} e^{x^2} \,dx$$

I was given the hint that
$$\int_0^{\infty} e^{x^2}dx =\int_0^{\infty} e^{y^2} \,dy$$
and was suggested to calculate
($\int_0^{\infty} e^{x^2} \,dx$)($\int_0^{\infty} e^{x^2} \,dx$) but I'm not sure where to start.  Looking at the graph, the integral diverges, so I am confused on how you could evaluate the integral in any way.

Comment: Was it $\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\,dx$?

Comment: Is it possible that you have a typo, and that you were actually asked to calculate the famous *Gaussian* integral $\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} \, dx$?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel we wrote the same speculative comment at the same moment!

Comment: I really don't think so, I looked over the problem again, and it is a positive exponent, although the problem may have been written incorrectly ( has happened before ). but in the case it is written correctly, can it be solved?

Comment: As written, the integral simply diverges (the integrand always exceeds $1$ which is already enough for divergence), so there is no value that can be ascribed to it. I echo the other comments that there must be a negative sign missing in the exponent.

Comment: Ok, thank you.  I'll have to give my professor an email.  I was mainly confused because of it diverging like you said.

Answer (score -1):

Further hint (without just solving the problem): You can combine
$$
\Bigl( \int_0^\infty \!e^{-x^2} \, dx \Bigr)^2
= \int_0^\infty \! e^{-x^2} \, dx \; \cdot \; 
\int_0^\infty \! e^{-y^2} \, dy
$$
into a double integral over the first quadrant of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and change to a different coordinate system to evaluate it.